# Is there is any way to convert my total XIB files to iOS6.1 from iOS7?

Tags: ios, ios6, ios7

Already i have developed application in iOS6 but after updating to iOS7. Xcode automatically changed all view with Flat UI iOS7.

But i don't want to update my UI to Flat. How to revert back my UI to iOS 6.

My Project has more than 100 XIB, 
Now i am manually going to each XIB and changing

In Interface Builder Document
 "View as" ---> iOS6.1 and earlier

**Important:** Is there is any way to convert my total XIB files to iOS6.1??

Comment: That depends on your revision control system.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, and with help of the version control, I've just discarded all changes for xibs and storyboards.

Only thing that comes to my mind without using source control is downloading some XCode 4 compatible xib (search on GitHub) and comparing its source (XML) with XCode 5 xib.

Comment: Maybe snapshots available from XCode?